# Lucene commits are very slow

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I need to load in the file path and content of over 100k files. These files vary in size and some can be quite large.
When testing with 2-3k files a commit takes a few seconds.
When testing with 100k files the application freezes up for multiple hours (possibly indefinitely).

This is how I create the writer.

```
final IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

final TieredMergePolicy t  = new TieredMergePolicy();
t.setForceMergeDeletesPctAllowed(.01);
config.setMergePolicy(t);
config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(128);

writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
writer.forceMergeDeletes();
writer.commit();
```

What are possible solutions to this?

Comment: You can always start by increasing the RAM buffer size from 128M to something much larger. Be sure to check your heap size as well, if you are running with too little memory you spend all your time on GC.

Comment: How much larger? The most RAM we can give is 12gb.
Also would it help if I committed more often (E.g. Every 5 minutes)? I've been questioning if it's because I'm doing it in bulk at the end too.

Comment: Measure, there is no way I can tell. 128M is very little. Perhaps you can start with 1G for the buffer and 8G for the heap and see what happens. Increase/decrease and measure. Plus be sure to log GC activity.

Comment: The other solution is to commit the files a few at a time.